# Configure cgroups v2 for fair resources sharing between users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, cgroups

Is there a way to restrict system resources to users? I know that used to exist a way of forcing every newly spawned process of a user into the specified cgroup by using cgred service along with /etc/cgconfig.conf file, as explained here [How can I configure cgroups to fairly share resources between users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5106/how-can-i-configure-cgroups-to-fairly-share-resources-between-users?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, this approach seems to be deprecated and the only way I've found is to modify cgroup attributes here /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-${UID}.slice by using systemctl set-property utility, the problem with this is that systemd creates this cgroup only when the user is logged, it gets removed as soon as user logs out. I am finding a way to restrict user resources even if he is logged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across a solution.

1. Create slice configuration file for each user:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/user-<uid>.slice.d
   sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/user-<uid>.slice.d/override.conf
   ```
2. Configure resource control, for example:

   ```
   echo "[Slice]
   Slice=user.slice
   MemoryHigh=2G
   CPUWeight=20" |  sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/user-<uid>.slice.d/override.conf
   ```

3. Apply changes:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   ```

You can check if it worked by reading the appropriate user slice cgroup attributes and check if they match with the values you choose, for example:

```
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-<uid>.slice
cat memory.low
cat cpu.weight
```

Comment: (1) I changed “Be careful to the spaces” to “Be careful *with* the spaces”, because “Be careful to the spaces” is not standard English.  But, either way, what do you mean by that?  (2) You need to do `echo … | sudo tee …` not `echo … > sudo tee …`.  (You had it right the first time.)  (3) You might want to choose either *`<uid>`* or `${UID}` and use it consistently.  (4) In the verification step, what is  `<cgroup_attribute>`? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Iam searching for the exact same solution. Share CPU equally between all users. Did your solution achieve this? If one users gets a slightly higher Weight, it could consume more CPU as others, right?